# Jackson is mistaking object field with JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson, polymorphism

Here is a  (a part of) server response:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "update_id": 489881706,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 5,
        "from": {
          "id": 188474643,
          "first_name": "Alireza",
          "last_name": "Mohamadi",
          "username": "SuNova"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 188474643,
          "first_name": "Alireza",
          "last_name": "Mohamadi",
          "username": "SuNova",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1462608191,
        "text": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I created a `Result` class which is like (Trimmed to reduce code):

```
public class Result
{
    private TObject[] result;
    private boolean ok;

    public void setOk (boolean ok) //Rest of the code

    public void setResult (TObject[] result) //...

    public TObject[] getResult () //...

    public boolean getOk () //...

}
```

And I have an `Abstract Class` called `TObject`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo (use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes ({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type (name = "chat", value = Chat.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type (name = "message", value = Message.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type (name = "message_entity", value = MessageEntity.class),
})
public abstract class TObject
{
    int update_id;
    boolean isUpdate;

    public void setUpdate_id (int update_id)
    {
        this.update_id = update_id;
        isUpdate = true;
    }
    public int getUpdate_id ()
    {
        return update_id;
    }
}
```

The problem is, because I used

```
@JsonTypeInfo (use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
```

it is not recognizing `update_id` as a field, instead it is recognizing it as a `JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME` and shows me:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not resolve type id 'update_id' into a subtype of [simple type, class org.telegram.objects.TObject]: known type ids = [TObject, chat, message, message_entity]
```

Now please tell me how can I tell jackson to parse `update_id` as a field of `TObject` and don't confuse it as `JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME`?

Comment: I've edited question and improved it. Now I think it's no more vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain what's going on here. So lets look at yours annotations:
Jackson will expect `Result` to have this format. `{ "ok": true, "result": []}` and this part is right. But `TObject` has

```
@JsonTypeInfo (use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
```

And `JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT` means that jackson will try to find `{"chat":{}}` or `{"message":{}}` or `{"message_entity":{}}` inside result array. Here is demo:

```
{ "ok": true, "result": [{"chat":{}}, {"message_entity":{}}, {"message":{}}]}
```

But the first element you have in your json is actually a `update_id`. And jackson can't find any `update_id` type that's why he just stops parsing and throws you an exception. So answering your question: `how can I tell jackson to parse update_id as a field of TObject and don't confuse it as JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME` : **It can't be done with JsonTypeInfo**, because jackson doesn't even thinks that this part is from `TObject`. He will try to find `TObject` 1 layer lower in json. If you can't change your json, you have to completly restructure your classes or create custom deserializer.

I made small demo how you can use `@JsonAnySetter` and  `@JsonAnyGetter` here: https://gist.github.com/varren/766b6830878c9e15c51784f57b303646#file-jsonanygetter-and-jsonanysetter

Custom `JsonDeserializer` and `JsonSerializer` for Update class in this demo can also work. https://gist.github.com/varren/766b6830878c9e15c51784f57b303646#file-custom-deserializer-and-serializer

Just remove all typeinfo annotations and add

```
private static class TObjectDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<TObject> {
    @Override
    public TObject deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonNode tree = p.readValueAsTree();
        tree.get("chat");
        TObject resultValue = null;
        if(tree.has("chat")){
            resultValue = p.getCodec().treeToValue(tree.get("chat"), Chat.class);
        }else if(tree.has("message")){
            resultValue = p.getCodec().treeToValue(tree.get("message"),Message.class);
        } else if(tree.has("message_entity")){
            resultValue = p.getCodec().treeToValue(tree.get("message_entity"),MessageEntity.class);
        }
        if(resultValue!= null)
            resultValue.setUpdateId(tree.get("update_id").asInt());
        return resultValue;
    }
}

private static class TObjectSerializer extends JsonSerializer<TObject> {
    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    @Override
    public void serialize(TObject value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();

        gen.writeNumberField("update_id", value.getUpdateId());
        String key = "";

        if(value instanceof Chat){
            key = "chat";
        }else if(value instanceof Message){
            key =  "message";
        } else if(value instanceof MessageEntity){
            key = "message_entity";
        }
        gen.writeFieldName(key);
        gen.writeRawValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(value));

        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm enjoying reading your complete answer and I will mark it as answer when I get every aspect, because it's not an ordinary answer and is more like a lecture.
Anyway I've got some questions. 1st: Why you used `@JsonIgnore` on `TObject` fields? Doesn't this cause Jackson to ignore getter and setter for `update_id`?
2nd: Why did you use `@JsonProperty` on every field, while they could be recognized even without annotation?

Comment: @AlirezaMohamadi  1) i use custom `JsonSerializer` and i don't want to serialize updateId inside message. I want to get `{"update_id":1,"message"={}}` but if i don't ignore update_id i will get `"message"={"update_id":1}` that is why i manualy insert `update_id`  on the same lvl with `message` in serializer. and prevent default serialization with @JsonIgnore  2) i used http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate all the POJO. and as you can see sometimes field names a little bit different `@JsonProperty("message_id") public Integer messageId;` but sure, you can use any approach you like here.

Comment: @AlirezaMohamadi btw i made an assumption that your TObject jsons have structure like this:`{ "update_id": 1,  "message": { ...}}` or `{ "update_id": 1,  "chat": { ...}}`  or `{ "update_id": 1,  "message_entity": { ...}}` so if this not what you asked, then i should probably update my post)

Comment: Nothing less than perfect. Thanks!
Also your assumption was true no need to update anything.